# How to save object, var, array in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, local-storage

In my controller i have this petition $http:

```
    $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/nPanelarencion/app/php/consulta.php',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
})

  .then(function(data) {
     var dat = data.data;

     for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
       dat[i]
      var runum = dat[i].rut +","+ dat[i].numero
      console.log("show: ",runum);
      localStorage.setItem("rutnum",runum);
     }
  });
```

in my `console.log(runum)` show this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwhfl.png)

The problem is that in my localstorage I only save one number, 
overwriting the previous variable. In the other controller->function i have this:

```
      function loadAll() {
    var rut = localStorage.getItem("rutnum").split(",")[0];
    console.log("el rut es: ",JSON.stringify(rut));


    var num = localStorage.getItem("rutnum").split(",")[1];
    console.log("El numero es: ",parseInt(num));
    var finalnum = parseInt(num)

    var repos = [
      {
        'rut'      : rut,
        'numero'   : finalnum

      }

    ];
    return repos.map( function (repo) {
      repo.value = repo.rut.toLowerCase();
      return repo;
    });
  }
```

Showing in my html is only one number and not all the rut numbers like I want.

This is the pic of localstorage:

[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHBud.png)

Comment: Are you overwriting the value of  `rutnum` in localstorage each time?

Comment: yes i overwriting  the value

Comment: do you have a any solution for me ? please.

Comment: It only stores one value because you keep overwriting it. Localstorage is a map, if you want many values they must have unique keys.

Comment: but how save all values in Localstorage, i need parse? but how?

Comment: You can use `JSON.stringify()` before safe and `JSON.parse()` after get from localstorage. You can save object with array and just push new data to this array.

Comment: Add a unique key for each value that you store. Right now you are only using "rutnum". In your case you could use the the 'i' in your for loop for example. I don't know what your data represents or what your use case is, so there may be more appropriate keys.

Answer (score 0):

Just push all of your objects in an array, then save this array using `stringify` in the local storage:

```
.then(function(data) {
     var dat = data.data;
     var runum = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
       dat[i]
       runum.push(dat[i].rut +","+ dat[i].numero);
       console.log("show: ",runum);
     }

     localStorage.setItem("rutnum",JSON.stringify(runum));
  });
```

When you need the data back from storage you have to `parse` them:

```
var my_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rutnum"));
```